# Fire on widgets_init only on dashboard

Tags: widgets, dashboard, init

I have an interesting issue. I need to launch an action on `widgets_init`, but ONLY on the WordPress Dashboard. So I can't use dashboard related hooks, because they fire too late; it has to be on `widgets_init`. How can I do this?

I was asked to expound more; not sure there's a ton more to expound on, but here it goes.

Again, at the core, I simply need to have functions fire on `widgets_init`, but ONLY on the WP Admin Dashboard screen.

The reason for this is that I'm building out a plugin that integrates the WP widget system into the Dashboard widget system. This allows me to provide the widgets interface for use in displaying Dashboard widgets. The thing is, I only want these widgets to be added on two screens, the widget edit screen, and the dashboard. The widget edit screen is easy for me, because there's a `page` query param, but the dashboard is a little more difficult.

I'm not able to grab the `current_screen` object until after `widgets_init` is fired, but by in order for the widgets to function properly, the MUST be added on `widgets_init`, that's simply what WP requires.

Comment: I like your question, but why do you have needs?

Comment: It's part of a plugin that integrates the widget system into the Dashboard widget system.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still can not figure out why you need to use dashboard related hooks in `widgets_init` action. Please, [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/188800/edit) and explain exactly what you are trying to do and add a sample code if possible.

Comment: I've edited my answer @cybmeta